# What's the difference between _b and b in this place

Tags: python

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self._b()#why here use _b,not b,What's the difference
        self._c='cccc'#why here use _c,not c,What's the difference
    def _b():
        print 'bbbb'
```

a.py

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self._b()#why here use _b,not b,What's the difference
        self._c='cccc'#why here use _c,not c,What's the difference
    def _b(self):
        print 'bbbb'
```

b.py

```
from  a import *
b=a()
b._b()
print b._c
```

it print 
bbbb
bbbb
bbbb
bbbb
cccc

Why can print out these, aren't _b and _c private variables.

Comment: There are two types of answers below.  Literal and perceptive.  The perceptive folks try to anticipate what you are really asking, while the literal folks just answer the (poorly written) question.  Both are valid, IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difference between single and double underscore:

```
class Foo(object):

    def regular_method(self):
        print 'ok'

    def _soft_private(self):
        print 'ok'

    def __mangled_private(self):
        print 'ok'

f = Foo()
f.regular_method()
# prints ok
f._soft_private()
# print ok
f.__mangled_private()
# error! no such attribute. BUT:
f._Foo__mangled_private()
# prints ok
```

So in essence there is no real "privacy" in python, but convention of using single underscore to warn developer using your API that he's doing so at his own risk.

Answer (score 10):

Prefixing a variable or function name with an underscore is a convention in Python to indicate that the variable is private. From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables):

> Private” instance variables that cannot be accessed except from inside an object, don’t exist in Python. However, there is a convention that is followed by most Python code: a name prefixed with an underscore (e.g. _spam) should be treated as a non-public part of the API (whether it is a function, a method or a data member). It should be considered an implementation detail and subject to change without notice.

Answer (score 8):

Per pep8 (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), a single underscore is intended to denote a "generally private" method or attribute.   The interpreter itself has no interaction with the single underscore, its more of a convention.   The double underscore OTOH has significance within the interpreter.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, the idea is that in Python convention, there are three levels of encapsulation/hiding.

1. Public attributes and methods: These are meant to be accessed by other classes without restriction.
2. Private attributes and methods (prefixed with an underscore): These are meant to be hidden from the outside world. The underscore serves as something like a warning to say: you shouldn't be touching this method unless you really know what you're doing. Primarily, this is used to differentiate between end users (the lesser mortals) and other developers.
3. There is a third level called mangled. Any attributes/methods that are mangled are basically not to be touched by anyone who is not the author of that code. It is important to the core functioning of the program and should not be touched, because if it is misused, then it may lead to unwanted/unplanned behavior.

In your case, the '_b' method is a private method. The author of this code wants to let you know that this is not meant for public use, rather if you are writing a wrapper around this class or something of that nature (basically if you are developer using this class), then you may use that method. Otherwise, it is better that you don't.

Also, a single underscore in front of a variable(or method) ties it to that class. So when `a._b` is called, the interpreter looks for it in the definition of the class `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice that `b` isn't defined anywhere. While `_b` is.

Unless you're asking why that naming convention is being used, in which case, you should ask the author of that code.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, take the time to leave a message explaining why. Common courtesy, you know?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but "underscore means private" is a helpful answer. "Ask the author of that code" is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The underscore is simply used to denote that the variable is private.

Comment: It should be noted that "private" does not mean "inaccessible". It's merely a convention used in Python and nothing more.  If you really want something to be private prefix it with two underscores, but even then it is still accessible; just not as easily.

Answer (score -1):

The class object `a` has an attribute `_b` which is found when asking for `self._b`.  The same class object `a` has no attribute `b`.

`_b` and `b` are as different as `beehive` and `zulu`.

You will get a parameter error when calling `self._b` because Python will implicitly pass `self` as the first argument to a bound method.  The signature should be:

```
def _b(self):
    print('bbbb')
```

Comment: This is a method, not an attribute. Consider revising your post

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: `_b` is clearly an attribute of the class object.  If you find that to be questionable, please read the documentation of the `type` builtin.  The value returned from this attribute will be a callable (a bound method).  It's just one of the things that makes Python so great!